# How to determine whether to perform segue based on JSON result from another thread

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, json

I have a login view. When user clicks "login" button, the app gonna authenticate the account then decide to segue or not. However, the `POST` request is asynchronous.

`- (BOOL)shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier sender:(id)sender`

is executed before I can get something from the server. Here is my code：

```
- (void)isAuthenticaionConfirmed
{
    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
    NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"account":self.studentsNumber.text,
                                 @"password":self.passwordToJW.text};
    [manager POST:checkAutenticationURL parameters:parameters success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);
        [self parseDictionary:responseObject];
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
        [self showAlert:@"3"];
    }];
}

- (void)parseDictionary: (NSDictionary *)dictionary
{
    NSString *errorInfo = dictionary[@"err"];
    if ([errorInfo isEqualToString:@"subsequent request failed"]) {
        [self showAlert:@"3"];
    } else if ([errorInfo isEqualToString:@"login failed"]) {
        [self showAlert:@"2"];
    } else {
        _name = dictionary[@"name"];
    }
}
```

here is the code relating to segue

```
- (BOOL)shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier sender:(id)sender
{
    if (_name) {
        return YES;
    } else {
        return NO;
    }
}
```

The `_name` here is the JSON result when the user uses correct account and password.

Answer (score -1):

I solve it by refusing any kinds of segue first

```
- (BOOL)shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier sender:(id)sender
{
    return NO;
}
```

then calling `[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"filterSegue" sender:self]` method in `paresDictionary`

It looks weird. If anyone has a better solution, welcome to leave a comment! :-)